# JavaScript Template System

Tags: javascript, html

currently I have coded a twitter widget using their API. However for some websites I need to change the layout and HTML structure which is outputted.

Currently I build the HTML like so:

```
// Generate HTML
var $con;
$con = $("<div>", { "class" : "tweet" })
  .append($("<div>", { "class" : "twocol" })
    .append($("<div>", { "class" : "tweet-profile-photo" })
      .append($("<img>", { "src" : obj.user.profile_image_url, "class" : "responsive-img" }))
    )
  )
  .append(($("<div>", { "class" : "tencol last" })
    .append(($("<div>", { "class" : "tweet-head" })
      .append($("<div>", { "class" : "eightcol" })
        .append($("<div>", { "class" : "tweet-name" })
                    .append(obj.user.name)
                )
        .append($("<div>", { "class" : "tweet-to-from" }))
      ))
      .append($("<div>", { "class" : "fourcol last tweet-date" })
                .append(((settings.disableDate===true)?"":fullDate))
            )
    ))
    .append($("<div>", { "class" : "twelvecol tweet-text" })
      .append($("<span>")
        .append(text)
      )
    )
    .append($("<div>", { "class" : "tweet-footer" })
      .append($("<div>", { "class" : "twelvecol", "style" : "display:none;" })
        .append($("<i>", { "class" : "fa fa-retweet", "aria-hidden" : "true" }))
        .append($("<span>", { "class" : "tweet-retweeted" }))
      )
    )
  );

$(container).append($con);
```

As I stated above, sometimes I need to change the layout and what is outputted, is there a way I can make some kind of template, so I could make a different header, then a different template for the body of each tweet. Then I can send this to the JavaScript and it will populate the HTML with the content.

Any ideas on how I could do this? I was thinking XAML or along them lines, it's like to keep it object based and not be searching strings or anything like that.

Comment: Handlebars or Mustache is what you are looking for

Comment: Why not build html using... html... Crazy i know. A templating lib would be better, but html is better than what you have...

Comment: Looking at the [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) templating engine. It's really simple to use and works perfectly for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jQuery templates](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl), it was simple, but did the job, I've worked with it and had good results.

Short presentation [here](http://skilldrick.co.uk/tmpl/)

**Later edit:** Seems it has been migrated to [jsRender](https://github.com/borismoore/jsrender)

**Later-later edit:** another lightweight Javascript-only version here: [JavaScript template engine in just 20 lines](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Javascript-template-engine-in-just-20-line)

Comment: Thanks for this, due to my intensions for it I can't really start setting up another large library, is there a way you could suggest I could do my own basic version?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I really love the last link. However, it could be changed a little. Adding `'use strict';` is a **very** good idea. Also, if possible, using `with` instead of always using `this.<something>`.